# Dynamics CRM 2013: Activity feed shows more than security role allows

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Dynamics CRM (relative) newbie here.

I have an activity feed set up on a users dashboard (I used the Personal Wall web resource).  If I look at the default posts for the Account view, everything is cool.

However, if I go and "follow" an Account when I look at my activity feed I can see other posts that relate to records that Account is involved with that are outside of my security role.  For example, that Account has several Case records.  My role has no permissions to Cases whatsoever, but there is the post in my activity feed.  If I click on the case I get a prvReadPriviledge error which is correct, but I don't want users to do this - I don't want these posts to show up in their feeds at all, even if the are following the account.

These posts do need to show up in the feeds for people working Cases, however (and their roles will have read/write to the Case entity).

I'm not sure what do here.. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you're looking for it's from Microsoft's site.

"The activity feeds walls are web resources that can be embedded in dashboards in context with relevant grids and visualizations. For example, you can embed the msdyn_/PersonalWall.htm web resource into a dashboard with specifying the HideUserProfile parameter. The default is value 1 (or, true), to hide the user profile, to unhide, use the value 0 (or, false). For more information about how to use web resources in dashboards, see [Analyze data with dashboards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327987.aspx)."